# Using conan packages in CMake: Library 'mylibrary.a' not found in package

Tags: c++, cmake, package-managers, conan

I am using cmake to build my project. I have a library, mylibrary, which is a dependency of my project. mylibrary is packaged with conan. I use the conan CMakeDeps and CMakeToolchain Generators when packaging mylibrary. This is the package_info function of mylibrary's conanfile:

```
    def package_info(self):

        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_find_mode", "config")
        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_file_name", "Mylibrary")
        self.cpp_info.components["libmylibrary"].set_property("cmake_target_name", "Mylibrary::Mylibrary")

        self.cpp_info.components["libmylibrary"].libs = ["mylibrary.a"]
        self.cpp_info.components["libmylibrary"].requires = ["gtest::gtest"]
```

My library is a shared library with the file name libmylibrary.a.I can package the library without having any problems. The find_package call in my projects CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
find_package(Mylibrary REQUIRED HINTS ${LLIB_DIR})
```

When I build my project, CMake does declare my library's target, which is mylibrary::mylibrary. But right I run cmake, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at MyProject/cmakedeps_macros.cmake:4 (message):
Library 'mylibrary.a' not found in package.  If 'mylibrary.a' is a system library,
declare it with 'cpp_info.system_libs' property
Call Stack (most recent call first):
MyProjectLibs/cmakedeps_macros.cmake:48 (conan_message)
MyProjectLibs/Mylibrary-Target-release.cmake:21 (conan_package_library_targets)
MyProjectLibs/MylibraryTargets.cmake:28 (include)
MyProjectLibs/MylibraryConfig.cmake:11 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:196 (find_package)
```

I am new to cmake's targets and I don't know what to do. I tried using uppercases or lowercases names when calling find_library, but it is not working. I suspect that I wrote something wrong in the package_info method.

Comment: Are you creating just 1 library inside the package? In that case, components are not recommended. Components should only be used for big packages like boost and others that contain many very different libraries. Then probably the best is to file a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, including the details of how you are consuming the library, how are you calling cmake with the toolchain, the full output, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did it. I don't understand why or how, but to solve my problem, I had to change this line:

```
self.cpp_info.components["libmylibrary"].libs = ["mylibrary.a"]
```

to this:

```
self.cpp_info.components["libmylibrary"].libs = ["mylibrary"]
```